# Program type already present: org.intellij.lang.annotations.Flow

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am getting this error whenever I try to run a program in Kotlin. My gradle files are like this: Project Level Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And App Level Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
ext.supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
ext.playServices = '11.6.2'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rossa.rossa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.appolica:flubber:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:2.2.3-support26.1.0'
}
```

Whenever I try to run the program I get this error

> Program type already present: org.intellij.lang.annotations.Flow Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.intellij.lang.annotations.Flow, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Please add following line in your App level build.gradle.

```
configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
}
```

Comment: Omg!  how do you even know something like this?  You saved me!

Comment: I tried and worked, but I did not understand the reason for this, explaining the problem briefly? thank you.

Comment: Working for me. 1000 clap to you.

Comment: I tried to vote up this answer but i could not... because I did one year ago.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what happens here ?

Answer (score 5):

Excluding the `jetbrains` annotations module is a workaround; why is it in your project in the first place? Most likely, it got automatically added to your classpath by Android Studio when what you really wanted was Android's own annotations.

So, a better solution is to look for an `org.jetbrains:annotations` dependency in your build.gradle file[s], like this:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
```

...and remove it.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it was just a glitch - "Clean project" helped.

Answer (score 0):

Program type already present:

```
org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$PatternFlags
```

Learn how to resolve the issue at: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.