# Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger, androidx

I migrate my project to AndroidX and I got these errors when building the project:

```
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'   
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'   
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'   
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'   
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.groupId}'   
[TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${project.version}'
```

I already tried several possible solutions:

- Clean Project
- Invalidate Cache and Restart
- Set `enableJetifier` to false
- Add option `--refresh-dependencies` to the compiler settings

Here is my project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        //not showing this
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.package"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 59
        versionName "1.5.2"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    // workaround for "duplicate files during packaging of APK" issue
    // see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/bl5Rc4Szpzg/wC8cylTWuIEJ
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

        //Workaround to an issue due to google play-services 11.0.0 + rxJava
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release_config

        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix " - debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "public"

    productFlavors {
        //not useful to show this
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation project(path: ':security')

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:annotation:3.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:processor:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart-processor:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'

    implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android-sqlcipher:1.4.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:twodscrollview:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.arasthel:asyncjob-library:1.0.3'
    implementation('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }

    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'

    implementation 'com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:2.2.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    implementation('com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:3.0.1') {
        exclude module: "support-v13"
    }
    annotationProcessor "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:3.0.1"

    implementation 'com.pascalwelsch.compositeandroid:activity:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.pascalwelsch.compositeandroid:fragment:27.0.0'

    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981467/3520621
configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I run `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace --debug --info` and here are some more info:

```
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.ArtifactTransformException: Failed to transform file 'dagger-compiler-2.2.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar} using transform JetifyTransform
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform 'C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.dagger\dagger-compiler\2.2\e411f732e5cd9697cdb291f6073b0d6ee2352023\dagger-compiler-2.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The type does not support '.' as package separator! Received 'java.lang.Object;Ljava.lang.Class'.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
```

So it seems **jetifier** and **dagger** are the cause, but **jetifier** is necessary for the migration to AndroidX and I don't want to remove **dagger**.

If I set `android.enableJetifier=false` I have more than 50 issues about DataBinding.

---

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the full Exception

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devDebugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:944)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitCollection(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitRootElents(AbstractFileCollection.java:234)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitRootElents(CompositeFileCollection.java:185)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultClasspathSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultClasspathSnapshotter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:329)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.createExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:151)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.access$100(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.getCurrentExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:208)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.ArtifactTransforxception: Failed to transform file 'dagger-compiler-2.2.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar} using transform JetifyTransform
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.UserCodeBackedTransforr.transform(UserCodeBackedTransforr.java:89)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformArtifactOperation.run(TransformArtifactOperation.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.access$900(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ParentPreservingQueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:378)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.access$600(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:172)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.call(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:209)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.call(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:202)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:177)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntiException: Failed to transform 'C:\Users\martin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.dagger\dagger-compiler\2.2\e411f732e5cd9697cdb291f6073b0d6ee2352023\dagger-compiler-2.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The type does not supp
ort '.' as package separator! Received 'java.lang.Object;Ljava.lang.Class'.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:204)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformArtifactsAction.apply(TransformArtifactsAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformArtifactsAction.apply(TransformArtifactsAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransfordFileCache$TransformAction.execute(DefaultTransfordFileCache.java:224)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransfordFileCache$TransformAction.execute(DefaultTransfordFileCache.java:211)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore$1.execute(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:111)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore$1.execute(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore.doAdd(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:160)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore.add(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultPathKeyFileStore.add(DefaultPathKeyFileStore.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransfordFileCache$1$1.create(DefaultTransfordFileCache.java:143)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransfordFileCache$1$1.create(DefaultTransfordFileCache.java:122)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:89)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:193)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:158)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransfordFileCache$1.create(DefaultTransfordFileCache.java:122)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransfordFileCache$1.create(DefaultTransfordFileCache.java:115)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransfordFileCache.loadIntoCache(DefaultTransfordFileCache.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransfordFileCache.getResult(DefaultTransfordFileCache.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.UserCodeBackedTransforr.transform(UserCodeBackedTransforr.java:87)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArguntException: The type does not support '.' as package separator! Received 'java.lang.Object;Ljava.lang.Class'.
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.core.type.JavaType.<init>(JavaType.kt:28)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.asm.CustomRemapper.mapValue(CustomRemapper.kt:49)
        at org.objectweb.asm.commons.thodRemapper.visitLdcInsn(thodRemapper.java:179)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1582)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readthod(ClassReader.java:1126)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.transform.bytecode.ByteCodeTransforr.runTransform(ByteCodeTransforr.kt:39)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:328)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.ArchiveFile.accept(ArchiveFile.kt:41)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.visit(Processor.kt:316)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.archive.Archive.accept(Archive.kt:66)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transformLibrary(Processor.kt:312)
        at com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor.transform(Processor.kt:175)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.JetifyTransform.transform(JetifyTransform.kt:199)
        ... 37 more
```

Comment: can you show logcats while you are not using this  android.enableJetifier=false
Please show complete logcats

Comment: Not sure about what you're asking for. If my project doesn't compile I don't have any logcats. With `enableJetifier` set to `true` I have the above errors  (failed to resolve ...) and if I set it to `true` I have a bunch of `DataBinding` errors because it couldn't generate classes.

Comment: I added the full exception to my original post.

Comment: Did you try removing everything from the gradle and then readding after deleting project cache?

Comment: I just tried now. I deleted the gradle folder, remove everything inside the app gradle file and the project gradle file and then run the 'clear cache' but the result is the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After migrating to androidx, the Android Studio can't resolve `dagger-android` and `dagger-android-support` classes, like DaggerAppCompatActivity. [Issue link](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1188)

Comment: I upgraded my dagger version to the latest (2.18) and in fact it resolved the issue. I still had some errors but they have been quickly fixed and my project is now compiling with AndroidX. Thanks.

Comment: I upgraded my dagger and butterknife version to '2.23.2' and '10.1.0' consecutively and it worked for me. Thanks for the direction @Kourosh

Answer (score 16):

What I did to solve this is `File - Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

Comment: usually fixes alot of gradle issues :/

Answer (score 15):

I have all the time the same Problem, just add something in the Gradle an Sync Again, and the problem was solved, i think is a bug from Android Studio

Answer (score 4):

I solved this error by change variables in build.gradle(Module) to their versions,
for example I changed

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$version"
```

TO

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0-alpha03"
```

and solved:)

- problem happened after update to AndroidStudio to 3.3 Stable! version

I use Androidx,...but everything worked great before upgrade Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

The one more reason is Jetifier tries to jetify libraries that it isn't suppose to. 
Starting with Android gradle plugin 3.3.0-rc01 and 3.4.0-alpha04 there is a workaround to disable jetifying specified libraries by adding them to coma-separated list at `gradle.properties`:

```
android.jetifier.blacklist=byte-buddy,guava
```

The solution is found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119135578#comment5)

Answer (score 3):

When I faced this problem, I resolved by deleting all files under .gradle/. And then I opened android studio and build again. It was worked and resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by upgrade :

- Android Studio to version 3.5.1
- Gradle to 5.1.1 (from gradle-4.10.1)

  ```
  In gradle.wrapper.properties
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
  ```